# Excel, Specifying cell contents as a result of other cells

Tags: excel, cell, excel-formula

I don't use excel often, and I haven't really found a good solution to my problem. (which is probably really simple).

I would like to have a cell with a function in my spreadsheet that shows another cell value value that depends on yet another cell value.

Such as:

[image]

The **Best Deal** heading simply uses the formula

```
=MAX(D3,D1000)
```

But under Best Deal I would like to display the Name Test1 rather than the numeric value.

Another thing that would be nice to know, is if there is a way to know the maximum row with data in it. So rather than `=MAX(D3,D1000)` something like `=MAX(D3,Max(RowCount_InD))`

Obviously that function wouldn't work as I wrote it, but hopefully this pseudo code gives you an idea of what I mean. The purpose is that if more entries are added, it would be able to handle them.

I know this is possible, but I'm having some trouble. Hopefully I can get some help here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a combination of Index and Match. Match will find the position of the maximum value, and then Index will look in column A and return the data in that same position. So, your formula would be:

```
=INDEX(A$3:A$1000,MATCH(MAX(D$3:D$1000),D$3:D$1000,0))
```

Put that formula in F3. No hidden columns required.

Sorry, I missed the part about the expanding range. You can do that by using Count or CountA along with Offset. The new formula would be:

```
=INDEX(A3:OFFSET(A3,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0),MATCH(MAX(D3:OFFSET(D3,COUNT(D:D)-1,0)),D3:OFFSET(D3,COUNT(D:D)-1,0),0))
```

More complex, but it is basically the same except that it will expand as you add new values at the end.

Comment: This is a perfect answer. helped me out a lot. Thanks!!

Comment: Just tried the adding the offset piece. Seams to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is only one 'simple' way I can think of this, but it requires hidden columns (sorry).

set E1 = A1 and fill down all the way (Basically you are making a copy of column A in column E but you are using a formula so it will always be the same)

Then under 'Best deal' - put this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(D3,D1000),$D:$E,2,FALSE)
```

Then hide column E so it doesn't look like a mess. This way you do not need any fancy macro's and it will work everywhere because it is a normal formula.

Comment: Oh BTW this will mean that the FIRST max is always chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the input! worth an upvote. This works, but I agree Tim's answer is awesome! =)

Answer (score 1):

"Another thing that would be nice to know, is if there is a way to know the maximum row with data in it. So rather than =MAX(D3,D1000) something like =MAX(D3,Max(RowCount_InD))"

This is a called a dynamic named range.  Create a name for the ratio data, and set up the formula for the name range to be this:

```
=OFFSET($D$3, 0, 0, COUNTA($D$3:$D$1048576), 1)
```

More info here: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm

Then, assuming you name this named range ratio_data, your function could be referring to =MAX(ratio_data) in combination with index-match as suggested by @Tim Mayes.  The range will expand automatically as you add more data.

```
=INDEX(A$3:A$1000,MATCH(MAX(ratio_data),ratio_data,0))
```

Ideally, you can replace the A3:A1000 by a dynamic named range as well.

Comment: Another really good answer. Thanks!  Definitely +1. Wish I could mark two answers are correct. Thanks